# Windows.Networking.dll with Windows 8 Desktop app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, desktop-application

MSDN says that Windows.Networking.dll is available to be used with desktop apps on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 platforms but I am not able to find a way into it.

I tried using them with a Windows 8 Store App and it worked like music but Windows 8 Desktop App is something I am not able to get through with. Any help or pointers would be awesome

Comment: What do you mean "I am not able to get through with"? You can't find the namespace from your App? Have you tried referencing the dll directly? If you're able to reference the library, but nothing is happening when attempting to use it, have you made sure to add Networking/Internet to your App Declarations?

Comment: No I am not able to find the namespace within the app. When trying to add a reference to the dll, it does not exist in the .NET libs. Trying to browse and add it, it fails saying that dll is not valid. PS: I am trying it with Windows 8 Desktop App as MS says it is compatible. I am able to do this with Windows 8 Store App (Metro App)

Comment: Check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/a42897c2-c304-48bc-a7dc-83abbb35fab0/) out. It appears that you have to manually change the target of the app to 8.0, then add a reference to System.Runtime.dll, then add a reference to `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime`.